# Media feature hover in container queries

Tags: css, container-queries

Can we use media features in container queries?

For example,

```
@container (hover: hover) {…
```

Comment: for what purpose? using `.container:hover {}` should be enough to detect hover effect

Comment: Good point, that’s a better solution